# How can I get this text from h4?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, selectnodes

(Sorry about my english, I'm brazilian)

I'm trying to get the InnerText from a h4 tag using the HtmlAgilityPack, I managed to get that type of value in 3 of 4  tags in the web site that I need. But the last one is the most important and it just returns an empty value.

Is it possible, that the structure of how the website was build requires a different way to get this value?

This is the specific h4 that I'm trying to extract InnetText ("356.386.496,02"):

```html
<h4 class="text-black--opacity-60 fs-20 fs-sm-42 fs-lg-40 w-100 mt-3">
<span class="align-middle fs-12 fs-lg-12 pr-4">R$</span>
"356.386.496,02"
</h4>
```

I've tried this:

```cs
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(data);

var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h4[@class='text-black--opacity-60 fs-20 fs-sm-42 fs-lg-40 w-100 mt-3']");

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
//Result in console:
//=>
```

Note that the SelectNodes method doesn't return null, it find the h4 node perfectly, but the InnerText value is "".

Comment: Try Next Node Innertext.

Comment: Is it a method? Just find NextSibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace "356.386.496,02" with 356.386.496,02 or  with ""356.386.496,02""

this solution should be work

```
public static void Main()
    {
        var html = 
        @"<h4 class=""text-black--opacity-60 fs-20 fs-sm-42 fs-lg-40 w-100 mt-3"">
<span class=""align-middle fs-12 fs-lg-12 pr-4"">R$</span>
""56.386.496,02""
</h4>";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h4[@class='text-black--opacity-60 fs-20 fs-sm-42 fs-lg-40 w-100 mt-3']");

        foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Alaaeddine! The problem is that I have no control of the website. I don't know too much about html, so I'm not sure if the value is between " ". I just copy and pasted the code of the Chrome inspector tool, here is a screenshot: [link](https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/1223/BtaYB6.png)

Comment: can you give me the website link ?

Comment: The problem is when you download page with C# the inner html become empty, it's not the same case when you inspect elements of page because it's a dynamic value

Comment: How can I download it with the value in this element? I'm using this to download the html:
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/8695/uy1mHy.png

Comment: Try to get the value from server not from the HTML page

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I figured out how to get the value from the server and worked fine!